# Where can I find the disk size required to run a full node?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I found the full node sync size for mainnet here: https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault

But I'm unable to do it for testnets: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault

How can I find the data size of testnet?